# Field with value not exists (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

If I run this query:

```
SELECT
    wp_posts.ID,
    wp_posts.post_title,
    wp_posts.post_status,
    wp_postmeta.meta_key 
FROM
    wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE
    post_type = 'product' AND 
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cat_disabled' AND
    wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'on'
```

I get 5348 records, but doing the opposite (getting records where `cat_disabled` key and its value is NOT set, it takes forever:

```
SELECT
    wp_posts.ID,
    wp_posts.post_title,
    wp_posts.post_status,
    wp_postmeta.meta_key 
FROM
    wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE
    post_type = 'product' AND 
    wp_postmeta.meta_key != 'cat_disabled' AND
    wp_postmeta.meta_value != 'on'
```

How do I optimize this query to get products where there's no meta_key with value `cat_disabled` set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ID 
FROM
    wp_posts 
WHERE
    ID NOT IN ( SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "cat_disabled" ) 
    AND post_type = "product"
    AND post_status = "publish"
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having all the schema and some data to test, this is a suggestion :

```
SELECT
    wp_posts.ID,
    wp_posts.post_title,
    wp_posts.post_status,
    wp_postmeta.meta_key 
FROM
    wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE
    post_type = 'product' AND 
    wp_postmeta.post_id NOT IN
    (SELECT post_id 
    FROM wp_postmeta 
    WHERE meta_key = 'cat_disabled' AND
        meta_value = 'on')
```

Comment: That gives me 657840 records same as my query, I am expecting (19359 - 5348) records

Comment: Got it, just had to do `SELECT DISTINCT`, thanks anyway :)